# Cannot delete item that "does not exist"

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I can see the item in the browser and I can find and return the item in powershell, but when I try to delete the item, I get "Item does not exist.  The page you selected contains an item that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user."  The same error shows in powershell, in the browser, and in the ULS logs.  No further information is supplied.

Notes:

- In powershell as farm admin and local admin using $item.delete()
- In browser as SiteCollection Admin. Tried to delete in modal box and
  direct web link, also in sitemanager.aspx.
- I did not create the list, and it probably had lookup columns with restrictive delete enabled.
- I also notice the OOTB ID column has been renamed ([curious](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/11/how-to-rename-id-column-in-sharepoint.html))

Powershell used per request:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://site.url.com/path"
$list = $web.Lists["RFP"]
$fin = $list.items | where {$_['ID'] -eq 1}
remove-item $fin -force
```

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: List and item creation is all OOTB thorough the browser, no code.  Powershell is simple 4 line; get-web, get-list, get-item, remove-item.  What code can I provide that will help?

Comment: are you sure the item has ID 1?

Comment: Can you add items to the list? How many items in this list?

Comment: Yes it has ID 1.  I can find it with powershell and return the title to match

Comment: I can add and remove new items.  It is just this one. (maybe others, I haven't tried.)  There are only 7 items in the list.